# Python - Recursion and tree of a word

Tags: python, recursion, tree, cpu-word

I'm creating a little program that requires me to do the following:
Starting from a `word` I need to make all possible words according to the following rule: starting with the word `'help'`, `'help'` me become root of the tree, then every time I raise a point of the first type (`'h'`) and then the word becomes me `'elp'`, then I take always the word `'help'` but at this point I raise the second letter (`'e'`) and then the word becomes me `'hlp'`, then I take always the initial word `'help'` and lift up the third letter (`'l'`), and then the word becomes me `'hep'`, then I take always the initial word `'help'`, and I raise the fourth letter (`'p'`), and then the word becomes me `'hel'` .

Then later, in the words found (`'elp'`, `'hlp'`, `'hep'`, `'hel'`) I have to repeat the same thing until you get to the leaves. All of these words should be included in a list(also in the tree, obviously).
Obviously there is a recursion, but my problem is this ... in the recursion are not any good! :(

Thank you if you can help me, it's really important.

PS: Or rather, as I understand it, I have to create all possible combinations without changing the order of letters

Comment: Why is this important ? It doesn't sound like a real world problem, it actually sounds like some assignment by some CS professor who didn't want to do a real world problem. We don't write code here, and you have shown no attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: No excuse maybe I explained bad, I do not speak English and maybe Google translator did not understand what I meant:

I have to figure out how to form words as possible according to the rules I've written, but I do not want all the code, absolutely!

I would like to understand the reasoning by which, thanks to Python, I can do something like that.
If, for example, instead of deleting each time a letter I had to add I already know how to do, I already wrote the program. but in removing letters from a session string I find it difficult, thank you.

Comment: so post the code you have written - there is no point anyone giving you their example code, as it will be their code, in their style. What you need is a solution that you understand, which you can incorporate into your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code recursive function. This function should create new words and call itself with each new word as an argument. I would recommend you to read some documentation about strings in Python.

The sample function:

```
def getWords(word):

    result = {}

    for x in range(1, len(word)+1):
        newWord = word[0:x-1] + word[x:]
        result[newWord] = getWords(newWord)

    return result
```

Recursion is here: `result[newWord] = getWords(newWord)`. We call our function for every new word.

You may improve it with some if/else statements. Now it returns dictionary even for one char word.

```
{   'elp': {   'el': {'e': {}, 'l': {}},
               'ep': {'e': {}, 'p': {}},
               'lp': {'l': {}, 'p': {}}}
```